# How has the United States reacted to the 2018 Italian general election?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, italy

How have Donald Trump and other US politicians responded to the victories by the populist Five Star Movement and center-right coalition parties?

Comment: Italy had an election? I've not heard anything about it in the US media.

Comment: It's just three days since the election. Maybe the reaction take a bit more. Also, have you done any research on it? Maybe read the opinions in the NYTimes or googling a bit?

Comment: Which overwhelming victory? I see three blocks, from 24% to 37%, which are unable to form any coalition. No one can "overwhelm" the other. And center-right got demolished, it was the far-right Lega that profited the most, while Berlusconi's Forza Italia lost a large part of its voters.

Comment: I'm still in hope that  [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdhQzXHYLZ4) will be appointed

Comment: @Nebr Fixed the overwhelming. I guess I was clumping populism with the center-right coalition

Comment: It hasn't reacted.

Answer (score 3):

Google suggests that most haven't noticed yet.  I did find an article talking about [Steve Bannon](https://www.politico.eu/article/steve-bannon-italy-election-like-us-donald-trump-vote/).  He is quoted as saying

> This is just a populist victory and should send a massive signal to the permanent political class in Rome and more importantly to the permanent political class in Brussels that people want change

You can read more on [Die Weltwoche](https://www.weltwoche.ch/ausgaben/2018-9/artikel/steve-bannon-italian-election.html).

I would suspect that Italian politics is low on the list of priorities of most in the United States.  We might see more in a week or two, once the media has a chance to learn more and ask questions of US politicians.